# Excel VBA formatting textbox in userform to display correct decimals and percents

Tags: vba, format

I'm having difficulty to figure out how to correctly format the textboxes in my simple form.
Here's my code:

```
Private Sub cmdCalculate_Click()
If IsNumeric(Me.txt_odds.value) Then
    Me.txt_odds = Format(txt_odds.value, "0" & Application.DecimalSeparator & "00")
End If
Me.txt_Minimum = Format(100 / txt_odds.value, "0" & Application.DecimalSeparator & "00%")
End Sub
```

However, I get the following results:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzrn0.png)

If I enter, for example 1.5 and expect it to be 1.50 I actually get 15.00.

Looking forward to your help. Thanks!

Comment: Your local decimal separator probably is a comma, not a point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved as follows:

```
Dim vTR As String

    vTR = Replace(Me.txt_odds.value, ".", ",")
    Me.txt_odds = Format(vTR, "0.00")
    If IsNumeric(Me.txt_odds.value) Then
         Me.txt_Minimum = Format(100 / vTR, "0.00") & "%"
    End If
```

Comment: Never handle number values as text.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you dividing 100 be the value in txt_odds?

Shouldn't it be the other way round?

```
Private Sub cmdCalculate_Click()
    If IsNumeric(Me.txt_odds.Value) Then
        Me.txt_odds = Format(txt_odds.Value, "0" & Application.DecimalSeparator & "00")
    End If
    Me.txt_Minimum = Format(txt_odds.Value / 100, "0" & Application.DecimalSeparator & "00%")
End Sub
```

Comment: No, it is correct. I need to find percentage. I'm having a problem with formatting the txt_odds textbox. For example, if i write 1.9 it becomes 19.00 instead of 1.90. But if i write 2 then it shows correctly 2.00

Comment: If I try your code with 1.9 it returns 5263.16% in the txt_Minimum textbox, with 2 it shows 5000.00%. What are you actually trying to calculate/display?

Comment: Well, in my case, on my PC when with 1.9 I get 526,32% and instead of 1.9 in txt_odds I get 19,00. We see different results maybe for the reason that we are in different locales. (comma and dot issue). As for 2, yes, I get 5000,00% instead of 50,00%. If I do same calcs in Excel it is correct. I get 50,00% (=100%/2), with 1.9 I should get 52.63% (=100%/1.9)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub cmdCalculate_Click()

    Dim Odds    As Double

    If IsNumeric(Me.txt_odds.Value) Then
        Odds = Val(Me.txt_odds.value)
        Me.txt_odds = Format(Odds, "0.00")
        Me.txt_Minimum = Format(Odds, "0.00%")
    End If    

End Sub
```

Comment: I have changed a bit your code and results are positive!
    Dim Odds    As Double
    Dim min     As Double
    If IsNumeric(Me.txt_odds.value) Then
        Odds = val(Me.txt_odds.value)
        min = 1 / Odds
        Me.txt_odds = Format(Odds, "0.00")
        Me.txt_Minimum = Format(min, "0.00%")
    End If

The only thing that is not working, when in textbox txt_Odds i enter something like 1.6 and then select 6 and replace it with some other number, I get 1,00 in the textbox txtOdds, instead of the number I entered.

Answer (score 0):

try using, cdbl instead value of textbox,

```
Private Sub cmdCalculate_Click()

    Dim Odds    As Double
    on error resume next ' if cant convert will skip
    Odds = cdbl(Me.txt_odds.text)
    Me.txt_odds = Format(Odds, "0.00")
    Me.txt_Minimum = Format(Odds, "0.00%")


End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this, i still get 15.00 instead of 1.50 in txt_Odds textbox

Comment: That's because `CDbl` requires a localised decimal separator, while `Val` always expects _dot_ as the decimal separator.